# Is there a way to implement an event like "BeforeSelect" in the treeview?

Tags: vb6

Consider a TreeView control containing multiple nodes. On selecting a node, certain information is displayed on a text box. This information can be modified and saved. Accidentally, if a user navigates to a different node without saving, a pop is displayed asking the user to save or cancel the action. If cancel is clicked, selection should remain on the previously selected node instead of a new node.

The logic to display pop up is written in BeforeSelect() event of TreeView. Below code works fine in c#.

But it is not working in case of VB6 because we don't have a BeforeSelect Event in VB6. **Is there any way to achieve this in VB6**?

```
private void TreeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender,TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    If(Check for anychange)
    {
        e.Cancel=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for poor editing

Comment: You can find help for code formatting here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: There isn't a `BeforeSelect` event in `MSComctlLib.TreeView`, so I would suggest you handle `NodeClick`, manually track which node was active prior to it, and manually select it.

Comment: @GSerg is right